# Why is my do-while loop not working?

Tags: java

When I compile, that try to enter (y) to play again my do - while is not working, it takes me out of the loop.
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class HiLo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating a play again variable
        String playAgain = "";
        // Create Scanner object
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Create a random number for the user to guess
        int theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        int guessNumber = 0;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 - 100: ");
            while (guessNumber != theNumber) 
            {
                guessNumber = scan.nextInt();
                if (guessNumber > theNumber)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, try again too high!");
                }
                else if (guessNumber < theNumber)
                {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, try again too low!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Congrats, you got it!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n)?");
            playAgain = scan.next();
        } while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye.");
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: After you type `y` to play again, and the `do` loop starts over, what are the values of `guessNumber` and `theNumber`? They still equal? If so, why wouldn't it skip the loop immediately?

Comment: Also, if you do end up playing again, shouldn't the random number to guess be .... *different*?

Comment: Could you please provide the data entered and outputted in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code as below: (You just need to update the variables inside the loop)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creating a play again variable
    String playAgain = "";
    // Create Scanner object
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Create a random number for the user to guess
    int theNumber = 0;
    int guessNumber = 0;
    do
    {
    // new lines to be added
    theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    guessNumber = 0;
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 - 100: ");
        while (guessNumber != theNumber) 
        {
            guessNumber = scan.nextInt();
            if (guessNumber > theNumber)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, try again too high!");
            }
            else if (guessNumber < theNumber)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, try again too low!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Congrats, you got it!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n)?");
        playAgain = scan.next();
    } while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye.");
    scan.close();
}
```

Here is the execution of code on Jshell:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason the program is not working is because the do-while loop does one iteration before it gets to the "while" part. In your case, the program successfully finishes the loop after a user correctly guesses the number. Your program breaks because after that you are requiring the user to enter 'y' to continue endlessly without letting them guess a number. If they guess a number, the program terminates.